# HTML generate rowspan in html table string

Tags: c#, html, html-table, html-agility-pack

I have the following code, which adds rowspan to a datatable in an html string, but I want it not to receive as a parameter a datatable, but instead to receive as a parameter an html string in C#.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Subject");
    dt.Columns.Add("Code");
    dt.Columns.Add("Test");
    dt.Columns.Add("Class");
    dt.Rows.Add("Math", "9", "ABC", "D1");
    dt.Rows.Add("Math", "9", "ABD", "D2");
    dt.Rows.Add("Math", "9", "ABE", "D3");
    dt.Rows.Add("Math", "9", "ABF", "D4");
    dt.Rows.Add("Science", "91", "ABG", "D1");
    dt.Rows.Add("Science", "91", "ABH", "D2");
    dt.Rows.Add("Science", "91", "ABI", "D3");
    dt.Rows.Add("English", "191", "ABJ", "D1");
    Label1.Text = ConvertDataTableToHTML(dt);

}
public static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(DataTable dt)
{
    string html = "<table border=1>";
    //add header row
    html += "<tr>";
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        html += "<td>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</td>";
    }
    html += "</tr>";
    //add rows
    string sub = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        html += "<tr>";
        int count = dt.Select("Subject ='" + dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "'").Count();
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            if (j < 2)
            {
                if (sub != dt.Rows[i][0].ToString())
                {
                    html += "<td rowspan='" + count + "'>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
                }
                continue;
            }
            html += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
        }
        sub = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>";
    return html;
}
```

This is the result that I hope

[image: expected result]

Comment: Can you please provide a sample, what your code actually produces?

Comment: What's not working? Are you receiving an error? What output are you getting and how does it not match that output that you want? Please provide additional details. As your question is currently phrases, it is hard to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code, and a few ways you can improve your code:

1. `<table border=1>` is missing the quotes around the `1`. It should be `<table border='1'>`.
2. You are missing the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags around the row tags.
3. Instead of constantly using `+=`, use a `StringBuilder`.
4. To make your code cleaner, you can change some of your `for` loops to `foreach` loops.

Your code should be changed to something like this:

```
public static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(DataTable dt)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    //add header row
    builder.Append("<table border='1'><thead><tr>");
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        builder.Append("<td>");
        builder.Append(col.ColumnName);
        builder.Append("</td>");
    }

    builder.Append("</tr></thead><tbody>");

    //add rows
    string sub = "";

    ...

    builder.Append("</tbody></table>");

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

(Just apply the same concepts to the middle code that I removed.)